# How to get publisher.authors when you have book.publisher and book.author?

Tags: python, django

Fresh from the Djangobook tutorial using the Books app example, you have Book related to Author through a many-to-many relationship and Book related to Publisher. You can get a set of books associated with a publisher with p.book_set.all(), but what do you need to do to get a set of authors associated with a publisher (through the books published)?

This is the models.py as is:
http://pastie.org/457781

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that:

```
publisher = Publisher.objects.get(...)
authors = Author.objects.filter(book__publisher=publisher).distinct()
```

Comment: yep, but s/published/publisher/ on the first row (or vice versa on the second one, but I think you mean the r-version;-).